# Query multiple dates NOT greater than the current date

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a one to many relationship in my database where one event could have multiple dates. I need to find all those events which don't have any events greater than the current dates (i.e. events which have expired).

I am using the following to select all those events with dates in the future:

```
SELECT events.id AS id,events.picture,events.name,events.venue,events.city
FROM events,event_dates
WHERE event_dates.start_date >= DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY events.id ORDER BY events.id DESC
```

I'm not being very smart trying to reverse this, and get events where ALL dates are `< DATE(NOW())` or `NOT event_dates.start_date >= DATE(NOW())`

Which (or neither) is closer to the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT e.id,
       e.picture,
       e.name,
       e.venue,
       e.city
  FROM EVENTS e
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM EVENT_DATES ed
                   WHERE ed.event_id = e.id
                     AND ed.start_date >= CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: your knowledge of these queries shows off my ignorance as always

Answer (score 3):

You could simply do a where not in like

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE events.ID NOT IN 
(
 your current query here (but only select the id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I dislike subselects and am wondering why this could not just be done with a LEFT JOIN?

SELECT events.id AS id,events.picture,events.name,events.venue,events.city
FROM events
LEFT JOIN event_dates ON events.id = event_dates.event_id AND event_dates.start_date>=NOW()
WHERE event_dates.ID is null
ORDER BY events.id DESC;

The key thing is putting the date test in the JOIN criteria and not the WHERE clause. I believe it to be more efficient, particularly if you have an index on event_dates start_date column?